# "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3

Tags: sass, compass-sass

> I have successfully installed Sass and Compass-sass, but I'm having trouble importing Compass. showing this error ""Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3"
>
> Here is my compass import

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

> here is my config.rb

```
http_path = "../"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

> Please See attached Screenshot

[image]

> Please help me guys what i have write wrong in my code

Comment: How did you create your project? Using `compass create`?

Comment: Yes using compass create

Comment: Are you using anything else to compile(for e.g webpack etc.) or is it just sass cli?

Comment: i have used just sass

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Does that happen with a new compass project?